# Why do I get this error in DLNM_Meta analyse in R

Tags: r

I have a question regarding dlnm package in R. I am trying to replicate a simple example of DLNM_meta (code below) which connects temperature to morbidity. It is straight-forward but when I try to run the model I get:

```
Error in glm.fit(x = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,  : 
  NA/NaN/Inf in 'x'
```

I am extremely new to R and I am pretty lost. I would appreciate any help!
library(dlnm) ;
library(mvmeta) ;
library(splines);
library(tidyverse)
setwd("D:/Documents/2021-2024/first/subject")

```
fujian <- read.csv("20050101_20191231_fujian.csv",row.names=1)
alldata<- subset(fujian, month %in% 8:11)
dim(alldata)
head(alldata)
regions <- as.character(unique(alldata$area))
data <- lapply(regions,function(x) alldata[alldata$area==x,])
names(data) <- regions
m <- length(regions)
ranges <- t(sapply(data, function(x) range(x$tmean,na.rm=T)))
fqaic <- function(model) {
  loglik <- sum(dpois(model$y,model$fitted.values,log=TRUE))
  phi <- summary(model)$dispersion
  qaic <- -2*loglik + 2*summary(model)$df[3]*phi
  return(qaic)
 }
reg <- "A"`your text`
bound <- colMeans(ranges)
varknots <- bound[1] + diff(bound)/3*(1:2)
argvar001 <- list(type="bs",degree=3,knots=varknots,bound=bound,cen=mean(data[[reg]]$tmean))
arglag001 <- list(type="ns",df=3)
suppressWarnings(
  cb001 <- crossbasis(data[[reg]]$tmean,lag=21,argvar=argvar001,arglag=arglag001,group =           data[[reg]]$year)
)
summary(cb001)

model001 <- glm(case ~ cb001 + dow + ns(time,df=6),
         family=quasipoisson(),data[[reg]],maxit = 1000,na.action="na.exclude")
summary(model001)
fqaic001 <- fqaic(model001)`
```

Comment: Check the value of `reg` you're trying to extract `data` with, check if `data[[reg]]` indeed returns what is required to run a model on.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I'm sure reg is correct .Interestingly this error doesn't exist when my command lags to some specific value to run a model. That confuses me.

Comment: Are you sure, or did you check that reg is correct? According to your code above, reg doesn't exist, because ```reg <- "A"`your text` ``` throws an error ;-)

Comment: Thanks for your reminder, I checked my code, reg <- "A" and data[[reg]]$ can return data to city A.

Comment: I'm very sorry, I forgot to delete the prompt in the question box, this may have caused trouble to you

Comment: If it works now(?): all fine!

Comment: Yes, now the model can run.thanks!